# Unable to access "Helvetica Neue Ultralight Italic" font

Tags: fonts, fontspec, italic

I want to put some parts of my document in **Helvetica Neue UltraLight *italic***.

I use :

```
\fontspec{Helvetica Neue Ultralight} \selectfont   
\emph{...} ...
```

or :

```
\textit{...} ...
```

But none of 2 solutions seems to work, as the result is in **Helvetica Neue LIGHT *italic***

I checked that the font I want exists on my computer, in a whole `HelveticaNeue.dfont` package.

Comment: You can specify the font by file name. That will always work.

Comment: Which computer system are you on: Windows, MacOS X, or something else?

Comment: Related: [Working with arial or helvetica fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121061/50146)