# Working with arial or helvetica fonts

Tags: fonts

I want to use arial font, but it doesn't generate any document. I'm using Texpad software. I tried with `helvet` package, but it doesn't work. Here's my code, maybe I'm not right. Can you help me?

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{TITLE}
\section{TITLE}
\subsection{Subtitle}
\subsection{Subtitle}
\section{TITLE}
\lipsum
\subsection{Subtitle}
\subsection{Subtitle}
\subsubsection{Title}
\begin{easylist}
& Title
& Title
&& Subtitle
&&& Title
& Title
\end{easylist}
\subsubsection{Title}
\subsection{Subtitle}
\section{TITLE}
\subsection{Subtitle}
\subsubsection{Title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your document works fine for me with `xelatex` You can not use `pdflatex` or `latex` as that can not use system fonts and the `fontspec` package.

Comment: It works fine for me compiled with xelatex. Do you have Arial installed?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're right, but I have errors in my code when I use xeLatex, such as size of fonts, bolding text and another. Can I bold and resize text?

Comment: The headings in your example are already large and bold, to get bold in general text all normal latex commands work eg `aaaa \textbf{bbb} ccc` makes `bbb` bold.

Comment: Can you add in the question the errors you get?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Your code works perfectly for me but it must be compiled by `XeTeX`, not with `pdflatex`. Note also that you must have that True Type Font (.ttf) available in your system.

To obtain the default sans serif font with `pdflatex`, basically you only need add this line to the preamble, without any package:

```
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
```

To use the helvetica font as the default font with `pdflatex` you can add these lines:

```
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Please note that you **cannot** use `\usepackage{fontspec}` with `pdflatex`.

Tip: Go to http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/sansseriffonts.html for many other options.

Comment: How can I use Helvetica **Neue**? Using `\usepackage[neue]{helvet}` does not work

Comment: @Ooker I suppose that you're trying to use a TTF font? As explained above, these fonts should be compiled with xelatex or lualatex, **not with pdflatex**, and using a different preamble (not the showed in my answers, but that form  question of Isai, except that you must change "Arial" with the  name of your font).