# Installing Arial Font

Tags: fonts, installing, installing-fonts

I need to write my document in Arial font, and I have no idea how to install the font. Would anyone be able to give a step by step guide? I have tried to use other guides, but they get rather confusing.

Thank you.

Comment: First of all, i am sorry you have to use that font. Second, what operating system are you running? Are you using pdflatex or xelatex/lualatex?

Comment: Hello, i know Arial font is not the greatest, and I am using xelatex. Thank you.

Comment: Operating System? Do you have Microsofft Word installed?

Comment: XeLaTeX allows you to use system fonts. If you use MS Windows or macOS, Arial should be preinstalled. Hence, you don’t need to install Arial and just put `\usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{Arial}` into the preamble of your document.

Answer (score 4):

XeLaTeX allows you to use fonts that are installed on your computer. On current versions of MS Windows and macOS, Arial should already be installed system wide. Hence, an installation of Arial is not needed. For other operating systems that do not come with Arial pre-installed, just place the font file in the regular directory for fonts on your computer as you would do to install the font for other software such as Office.

The following MWE works on MS Windows and macOS with XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}

Hello world!

\end{document}
```

Just browse this platform for more concrete questions regarding the use of fonts with XeLaTeX. There are also several related questions on how to use Arial with LaTeX such as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23957/47927) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121061/47927).

Comment: Sorry to unearth such an old question, but jeschwar answered it just a few hours ago, so it popped up on my front page …

Answer (score 2):

I am also required to write a document with Arial font and thought I would share this in case someone else has the same question.

I placed the following in my preamble and used `pdflatex`:

```
\usepackage{arial}                           % load package which provides the font
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{ua1}               % set default serif font as Arial
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}    % set the default font as serif, i.e., Arial
```

The package documentation can be found [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/urw-arial)