# How to use helvetica font in online editor?

Tags: beamer, fonts, online

I am using overleaf.com for creating a beamer document. I want to change default font to helvetica. I addede following lines from answer posted for [Working with arial or helvetica fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121061/working-with-arial-or-helvetica-fonts) but it didnt work online editor.

```
\documentclass[x11names]{beamer} \usetheme{default} \usecolortheme{default}   
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % using non standard fonts for beamer 
\usefonttheme{serif} % default family is serif \usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{helvet}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For pdflatex you could just use the `helvet` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{helvet}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

In LuaLaTex or XeLaTeX, change the line

```
\setmainfont{helvet}
```

to

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Scale = 1.0]
```

You can also use Helvetica if you have a TrueType or OpenType version of that font installed, but TeX Gyre Heros is a free clone included with every TeX installation.